# How to take care of a sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough-starter

I am a beginner bread maker and just bought a San Francisco Sourdough starter.
The instructions ask to discard part of the starter on day 5 of activating the starter.
Why is that?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but note that discard doesn't really mean throw away in this case. "Use up" might be a better term and there are many good recipes for (unfed) starter discard.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/55179/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/91409/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75318/67 ;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sourdough starter - Have I been doing it wrong?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91409/sourdough-starter-have-i-been-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Your question about discarding has been asked many times before.  Please see the links Joe provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some of the starter is not removed, it becomes overly acidic.  Too much acid reduces the leavening effect of the starter.  Removing and feeding keeps the acid in balance.